# Points of tangency to a non-singular quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $P$ be an affine non-singular quadric. All possible tangents are drawn from the origin. Show that the points of tangency lie in one hyperplane. And how to find the equation of this hyperplane knowing the equation of a quadric?
[and tell me which book to read better to understand this topic, please]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$\tag{1}ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2dyz+2exz+2fxy+2gx+2hy+2iz+k=0$$

be the equation of the quadric. Then, the equation of the plane you are looking for is:

> $$\tag{2} gx+hy+iz+k=0.$$

Proof of (2): Let $M_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ be any point in $\mathbb{R^3}$. The set of points of  line $[OM_1]$ can be characterized as the set of $M_{\lambda}(\lambda x_1, \lambda y_1,\lambda z_1)$ (for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$). The intersection points of the quadric with this line are the $M_\lambda$ for which one has:

$$\tag{3}\lambda^2\underbrace{((ax_1^2+by_1^2+cz_1^2)+2(dy_1z_1+ex_1z_1+fx_1y_1))}_{A} \ + \ 2\lambda \ (\underbrace{gx_1+hy_1+iz_1}_B) \ + \ k \ = \ 0.$$

which is a quadratic equation in parameter $\lambda$, with zero, one or two real solutions (no intersection, tangency, or 2 intersection points).

We place two constraints on this line: it must be tangent to the quadric (thus (3) has exactly one solution) and the point of tangency  must be precisely $M_1$. Thus:

- the discriminant of (3) is zero, i.e.,

$$\tag{4}B^2-Ak=0,$$

- $\lambda=1$ is a root of (3), i.e.,

$$\tag{5}A+2B+k=0.$$

Multiplying (5) by $k$ and adding to (4), we obtain:

$$B^2+2Bk+k^2=0 \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ (B+k)^2=0  \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ B+k=0$$

proving that all tangency points lie in the plane with equation (2).

**Remarks:**

1) The plane with equation (2) is called the **polar plane** of the origin with respect to the quadric ("Polar plane" can be a good keyword for Internet searches). There is a direct method for obtaining the polar plane of a point with respect to a quadric, but it would take some time to describe and justify it, and I think you don't need that here.

2) The set of tangent lines issued from the origin is a cone.

Comment: h should be k in a couple of places.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: They have not been corrected: after equation (5), you should be multiplying (5) by k, and the next equation should read $B^2 + 2Bk + k^2 = 0$.

Comment: @Nick Thanks again. I appreciate. I correct now.